# What is the right syntax for NOW() function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get all rows from DATE column
values from 10 days ago till today

i'm trying to undesrtand why this syntax isn't working:

```
select * from table WHERE date BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() - INTERVAL 10  DAY ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to start with the lower value when using `between`

```
select * 
from table 
WHERE date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY and NOW()
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to the `NOW()` function but to the `BETWEEN` operator, the lower timestamp has to be specified first:

```
where date between now() - interval 10 day and now()
```

however, depending on your requirements, you might want to use this:

```
where date between current_date() - interval 10 day and current_date()
```

or just

```
where date>=current_date() - interval 10 day
```

`now()` returns a `timestamp` that contains date and time information, while `current_date()` returns just the current date without time information. If date is just a `date` column, without time information, using `now() - interval 10 day` you will get just the latest 9 days and not the latest 10 as you might expect.